# C# Winforms Chart BoxPlot define x-values

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, boxplot

I have a boxplot in my winform

```
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
```

It looks like this:

[image]

```
            Series dataSeries = new Series(fieldName);

                    dataSeries.ChartType = SeriesChartType.BoxPlot;

                    double[] dataPoints = new double[]{
                        values.Min(),
                        values.Max(),
                        StatisticsHelpers.Median(values.Where(x => x < median).ToArray()),
                        StatisticsHelpers.Median(values.Where(x => x > median).ToArray()),
                        values.Average(),
                        median
                    };

            dataSeries.Points.Add(dataPoints);
            chartAttributes.Series.Add(dataSeries);
```

How can I spread the data series across the chart? The current behavior is that the witdh of the used area around 1 stays constant and the individual boxplots share that area (the more boxplots, the thinner each one becomes). I guess it is somehow necessary to assign different x values to the boxplots, but I don't know how.

Comment: can you provide library name of StatisticsHelpers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour of fitting all `DataPoints` into the chart is normal. To change it you need to either:

- **Delete** points you don't want any more or
- Set a **range** of points to display.

To set the range you need **proper** `DataPoints`, i.e. one with a **numeric** `X-Value`.

You are using an implicit  `DataPoint` constructor that doesn't set the `X-Values`. So they all are being set to `0`

Instead you should always make sure that you have meaningful x-Values!

[This is an explicit constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456609%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that will let you do that.

If you do not want to assign a meaning to the X-Values you should at least set the to an increasing number!

Here is how you add a 'proper' `DataPoint`:

```
    dataSeries.Points.Add(new DataPoint(dataSeries.Points.Count, dataPoints));
```

Now that the points all have numeric X-Values you can control how many of them shall display. This is done by setting the `Minimum` and `Maximum` of the x-axis:

```
    yourChartArea.AxisX.Minimum = 2;
    yourChartArea.AxisX.Maximum = 7;
```

Now only points 2 to 7 are displayed.

If you actually are talking about the three series you show: The corresponding points of each series in a `Column`, `Bar` or `Boxplot` chart are **always grouped together**; you can't spread them away from the value they belong to.